# QR Code not showing result using Zxing

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am currently working with qrcode
I added Zxing library and also core.jar.
When I am trying to scan a document not getting any results.

```
qrscan_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Scan Result = " + data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
    }
```

I added CaptureActivity class in Manifest.
I am using Zxing 2.1[image: Screen shot]

Comment: If thats what you see, its probably because its too blury / not focused. So cannot determine the QR code

Comment: I tried with some other QR codes, But still its not working

Comment: Why aren't you using the IntentIntegrator helper class? https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent

Comment: But it needs Barcode apps to be preinstalled.

Comment: It does prompt the user to install it, if they dont have it. I found it easier to do that. Just a couple lines of code. It returns the string/number back to you.

Comment: Your code also needs the Barcode app installed, You are starting an intent with the Barcode app as target. The IntentIntegrator provides a dialog in case the app is not installed.